# QGIS Browser Panel Not Displaying all files

Tags: qgis

I'm new to QGIS and trying to 'repair data source' can't see the file I want to access in the browser panel. It's there in File Explorer but in the browser panel it's in a folder with a 'squiggle' above the folder icon. See image attached. I've tried the documentation but can't find out what's stopping me seeing it.

Can you advise me of what to do?

[image].

Comment: looks like  there is additional space in the filename .tif - remove the space drag and drop it into qgis.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The .tif is part of the folder name; it's not the file name.The file I'm after is in the Scheduled Test folder with the squiggle above it. I can't access this folder. Do you know what the squiggle signifies?

Comment: Can you see and add the file using the Open Data Source Manager?  Can you drag the file from Windows Explorer into the QGIS window?  What kind of a data source is the file?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm trying to move via a layer definition file a layer from one system to another. When I try your recommendation on the target system then QGIS says not not a valid or recognised data source. File names are identical on source and target systems. It's a vector file but on both systems its file type is simply 'file'. Sidecar .xml file is with the dataset. As an aside, do you know what the squiggle or shadow above the file icon signifies?